# Best way to find out what "page" of a paged UIScrollView you are on

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

Just wondering what the best way to find out what page you're on in a paged scroll view.

At the moment I have this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
  float page = scrollView.contentSize.width / scrollView.contentOffset.x;
}
```

is this the only way? Or am I missing some simple `scrollView.page` property or something?

... * goes to check * :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page is not really a code concept in a scrollview. The concept of a page in iOS is just a snapping between different sections of your scrollview. If you use a UIPageControl then the notion, and retrieval of a page is very easy, otherwise, your way is the way to go to determine the virtual "page"